# Convert a sql timestamp to java OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, sql, datetime, java-time, offsetdatetime

I need to convert some timestamps to `OffsetDateTime` in java. For example, I have the following time:

```
2020-07-31 13:15:00.000000000 -03:00
```

Should I use `SimpleDateFormat` to format this or some other helpers that are more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DateTimeFormatter` (the parsing and formatting API for the the [modern date-time classes](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)) as shown below:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-07-31 13:15:00.000000000 -03:00",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.n ZZZZZ"));
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-31T13:15-03:00
```

Check the documentation of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details on it. You can also check **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)** to learn more about the modern date-time API.

**Note:** `java.util` date-time classes are outdated and error-prone and so is their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. You should stop using them completely. Moreover, `OffsetDateTime` is part of the modern date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't fit with it.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).